# Compare data type in oracle where condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
to_t.COUNTRY_CD is varchar2(10 byte)

from_t.DESCRIPTION is varchar2(60 bytes)
```

I want to insert from_t.DESCRIPTION's data into to_t.COUNTRY_CD's

I need to filter out the bigger data, when I insert. Here is the sql I came up

I wonder how can I do something like `WHERE (from_t.DESCRIPTION <= 10 byte);`

```
MERGE INTO ADV_TEST_BACKFILL_COUNTRY to_t
  USING COUNTRY_CD from_t
  ON (to_t.COUNTRY_CD = from_t.DESCRIPTION)

  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (
    to_t.COUNTRY_CD,
    to_t.DESCRIPTION,
    to_t.CLOSED_IND,
    to_t.UPDATE_WHO,
    to_t.UPDATE_ON      
  )
  VALUES (
    from_t.DESCRIPTION,
    from_t.DESCRIPTION,
    from_t.CLOSED_IND,
    from_t.UPDATE_WHO,
    SYSDATE
  ) WHERE (from_t.DESCRIPTION <= 10 byte);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want [`lengthb()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions076.htm)?

```
where lengthb(from_t.DESCRIPTION) < 10
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not 100% clear to me what you want to achieve here... to me you probably don't want to "skip" lines with larger data but truncate it...

Anyway, since you are inserting a character string into a shorter one, you will need to extract a substring to make sure it doesnt bust the smaller column. Of course you will probalby "lose" some data (characters 11+ of `DESCRIPTION`).

```
VALUES (
   SUBSTR(from_t.DESCRIPTION,0,10),
...
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I need to rethink about "skip".